# Calculus Problem with Integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function over $[a,b]$ with arc length $L$. Show that there exists a value $c \in [a,b]$ such that the angle $\theta$ between the tangent line and the horizontal line at $x = c$ satisfies $|\cos\theta| = \frac{b-a}{L}.$
Hint(s):
$f'(a) = \tan(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent line and the horizontal line at $x = a$.

I have figured out that $f'(c) = \tan\theta$, and that $L = \int_a^b \sec\theta (dx)$. Where do I go from here? I was thinking of using the Intermediate Value theorem somehow, but I do not see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By basic trigonometry you have 
$$
|\cos\theta|=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}.
$$
If you think of $\theta$ as a function $\theta(x)$ with $\tan(\theta(x))=f'(x)$ (that is, $\theta(x)=\arctan f'(x)$, which is differentiable), we have 
$$\tag1
L=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\,dx=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta(x)}\,dx=\int_a^b\frac1{|\cos\theta(x)|}\,dx.
$$
By the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals, there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that 
$$\tag2
\int_a^b\frac1{|\cos\theta(x)|}\,dx=(b-a)\,\frac1{|\cos\theta(c)|}.
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ you haveh 
$$
|\cos\theta(c)|=\frac{b-a}L.
$$

Comment: Looks like we only need $f$ to be continuously differentiable, not twice.